# Read multiple text files from different directory using scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read multiple text files from a folder,but i am getting a strange result,maybe you can help me understand it.So

```
File folder;
int result;

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            //
            // disable the "All files" option.
            //
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            //
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "
                        + chooser.getSelectedFile());
                folder = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                Scanner in = null;
                for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                    try {

                        in = new Scanner(new File(fileEntry.getName()));

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

                    }
                    String CompositionName = in.next();
                    String Composer = in.next();
                    in.next();
                    String Duration = in.next();

                    parent.model.addRow(new Object[] { "", Composer,
                            CompositionName, TrackNumber, Duration });

                    in = null;

                }
            }
```

Using this method,i get to read only the first file of the folder.I get a NullPointerException  on String CompositionName = in.next(); during the second loop,even if the file name is correct.This way works,but i hear it is not good practice.

```
File folder;
int result;

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            //
            // disable the "All files" option.
            //
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            //
            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "
                        + chooser.getSelectedFile());
                folder = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                Scanner in = null;
                for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {


                    try {
                        System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                        in=null;

                        in = new Scanner(new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+fileEntry.getName()));


                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

                    }
                    String CompositionName = in.next();
                    String Composer = in.next();
                    in.next();
                    String Duration = in.next();

                    parent.model.addRow(new Object[] { "", Composer,
                            CompositionName, TrackNumber, Duration });

                }
            }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this :

```
in = new Scanner(fileEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to instantiate the file with just the File name. Unless you set the File's environment, this will fail (as File instances expect a valid reference).

From - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29:

It expects a File for the parent directory (which in your case is `folder`) and a String for the child's name (which is `fileEntry.getName()`)

As the other answer says,

```
new Scanner(fileEntry)
```

will work, as will

```
new Scanner(new File(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath())
```

and finally

```
new Scanner(new File(folder, fileEntry.getName())
```

will also work.

Comment: Could you explain why the first file was scanned correctly?Thanks.

Comment: Honestly not sure. I'd throw in a `System.out.println(fileEntry.getName())` in your `FileNotFoundException` clause to see what's going on.